# Computing an expectation of a function of an rv $E(f(X))$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, expected-value, self-learning

I am self-learning undergrad calculus-based probability from *Intro to Probability*, Blitzstein and Hwang. I would like to ask, if the below deduction is correct.

> Let $X \sim Geom(p)$ and define the function $f$ by $f(x) = P(X = x)$ for all real $x$. Find $E(f(X))$.

**Solution.** (My attempt)

$f(x) = (1-p)^x p$. So, the random variable $Y = f(X) = (1 - p)^X p$.

$Y$ takes values in the set $\{p,qp,q^2p,q^3p,\ldots\}$. The PMF of $Y$ is given by,

\begin{align*}
P(Y = y) &= P((1-p)^X p = y)\\
&= P(X \log q = \log y - \log p)\\
&= P\left(X = \frac{\log y - \log p}{\log q}\right)\\
&= q^{\frac{\log y - \log p}{\log q}}\times p\\
&= \frac{q^{\log_q y}}{q^{\log_q p}}\times p\\
&= \frac{y}{p} \cdot p\\
&= y, \quad \quad y \in \{p,qp,q^2p,q^3p,\ldots\}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
E(Y) &= \sum_{y}yP(Y =y)\\
&= \sum_y y^2 \\
&= p^2 + p^2 q^2 + p^2 q^4 + \ldots \\
&= \frac{p^2}{1 - q^2}\\
&= \frac{p^2}{p(1+q)}\\
&= \frac{p}{2 - p}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks correct, but you can shortcut it by appealing to [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician):

$$E[q^Xp]=\sum_{x=0}^\infty (q^{x}p)(q^{x}p)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty q^{2x}p^2=\frac{p^2}{1-q^2} $$